# Как мигрировать базу даннных IdentityDbContext?

Tags: c#, база-данных, asp.net

При миграции пишет ошибку:

```
    Checking if the context targets an existing database...
System.ArgumentException: The type 'ApplicationDbContext' does not inherit from DbContext. The DbMigrationsConfiguration.ContextType property must be set to a type that inherits from DbContext.
```

Пытаюсь включить миграцию:

```
Enable-Migrations -ProjectName * -ContextTypeName *.ApplicationDbContext
```

А самый код:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        
    }
```

Пишет ошибку при создании БД, но не понимаю, зачем он её пересоздает. Если во первых есть связи с другими таблицами, а во вторых ТАБЛИЦА СУЩЕСТВУЕТ

```
Failed executing DbCommand (35ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']                                                                                                                                     CREATE TABLE "AspNetRoles" (                                                                                                                                                                                                       "Id" text NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                            "Name" character varying(256) NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                            "NormalizedName" character varying(256) NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                  "ConcurrencyStamp" text NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                  CONSTRAINT "PK_AspNetRoles" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")                                                                                                                                                                             );                                                                                                                                                                                                                             Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P07: relation "AspNetRoles" already exists
```

Мне кажется миграция не правильно выполняется

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @AntonNikolaev  Почему то при обновлении пишет ошибку с таблицей: AspNetRoles
Но у меня её вообще нету, где и как её можно убрать??

Comment: сделайте чистой проект по образцу из доков и посмотрите будет ли такая ошибка вновь, больше не могу ничего посоветовать

Comment: также точки останова поставьте и гляньте в каком месте все падает

Comment: @AntonNikolaev, Спасибо, во время самой миграции падает сам текст ошибки:
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P07: relation "AspNetRoles" already exists

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос метку используемой ORM (EF 6, EF Core, etc). Добавьте в вопрос используемую СУБД (Postgres) и прочую необходимую информацию (сообщения об ошибках)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, извините что так долго добавил

Answer (score 0):

Добавил EF.Tools и все получилось.
Вернулся к прошлой версии, сделал миграцию.
После поставил новую версию, добавилась нужная миграция с необходимыми файлами. Все сработало!